# Combining three queries into one outer join in possible

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

Currently I have three queries like this:

```
var query1 = (from a in dbContext.Table1 
              where a.email == someEmail 
              select a.Table1K).ToList();
var query2 = (from a in dbContext.Table2 
              where a.emailAddrerss == someEmail 
              select a.Table2K).ToList();
var query3 = (from a in dbContext.Table3 
              where a.email == someEmail 
              select a.Table3K).ToList();

if ( query2.Any() || query3.Any() )
{
   return false;
}

if(query1.Count == 1 )
{
   var x = query1[0];
   // do some stuff with that x value ... 
}
```

Is there a way for example with outer joins ( I am not very good with outer joins ) that we can achieve this in one query instead of three queries ?

Comment: Well you're not actually _joining_ the tables so I'm not sure that's appropriate.  You could embed queries 2 and 3 into the _where_ clause, but without knowing what it returns after the "do some stuff" it's hard to know if that would be appropriate.

Comment: @DStanley  if queries 2 or 3 return anything, it is bad, we just return false and go out

Answer (score 1):

I don't think an actual join is appropriate, but you do have a few opportunities for improvement:

- Don't call `ToList` on queries 2 or 3 if you just want to check for *any*  result:
- If you only want *one* result from query 1, call `SingleOrDefault` instead

  ```
  var query1 = (from a in dbContext.Table1 
                where a.email == someEmail 
                select a.Table1K);
  var query2 = (from a in dbContext.Table2 
                where a.emailAddrerss == someEmail 
                select a.Table2K);
  var query3 = (from a in dbContext.Table3 
                where a.email == someEmail 
                select a.Table3K);


  if ( query2.Any() || query3.Any() )
  {
     return false;
  }

  var x = query1.SingleOrDefault();
  if(x != null)
  {
     // do some stuff with that x value ... 
  }
  ```